# how to on or off gps using toggle button Android

Tags: android, button, gps, toggle

How to on or off gps using toggle button Android

I want to on or off GPS according to GPS status using Toggle Button.

Thank You

Comment: You want to turn on/off GPS from your app using a button, right?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want to make it programatically?

Comment: yes, i want to turn on or off gps directly from my app using toggle button

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to turn the GPS on / off programmatically. Programmatic access is restricted to this setting. Instead you can take the user to the GPS Setting page using an intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

The permission to turn on/off the GPS in **totally restricted** and **you can not toggle that programmatically**. Instead, you should redirect the user to the Settings of the device, where she can toggle pn/off directly.

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
```